# Auto Delete Of Data From Database After A Fixed Time Interval?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I am using `sql server 2005.` In my project i wanna auto delete the data from the `database` after a fixed interval of time say (10 minutes); Is there any  automatic process to  delete the data  from the `database` without the user intervention.. I want to use the `event scheduler` i have created a `event scheduler` but its not working any help ???

this is the event i have created.

```
CREATE EVENT deletedata
ON SCHEDULE 
EVERY 10 MINUTE 
DO 
DELETE FROM user WHERE id=1
```

Comment: MySQL or sql server? Completely different things

Comment: so why does question say SQL server 2 hours later?"

Answer (score 2):

just go through the link [Microsoft schedule Jobs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)
Expand the SQL Server Agent node and right click the Jobs node in SQL Server Agent and select 'New Job'

In the 'New Job' window enter the name of the job and a description on the 'General' tab.

Select 'Steps' on the left hand side of the window and click 'New' at the bottom.

In the 'Steps' window enter a step name and select the database you want the query to run against.

Paste in the T-SQL command you want to run into the Command window and click 'OK'.

Click on the 'Schedule' menu on the left of the New Job window and enter the schedule information (e.g. daily and a time).

Click 'OK' - and that should be it.